# Writing to Network Folders with ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, directory

I'm having trouble accessing a network share using ASP.net C#.

I've used the identity in web.config

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="username" password="password" />
```

And changed the machine.config file. I've also enabled impersonation in IIS.

I try to use this code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("\\\\networklocation\\test");
```

And I get the following error:

Parser Error Message: Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

The network share location has access to all users (everyone account).

Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Comment: You could you make your life easier by moving the network content to a path in your web app.

Comment: @jrummell there are valid reasons for needing to access network shares from a webapp, and I personally have successfully done so using identity impersonation.

Comment: Isnt the authenticating account on the remote share the apppool identity?

Comment: @Richard not if impersonation is used.

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes I agree 100%, I'm just saying it complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the correct domain for the user?

```
<identity impersonate="true"
          userName="domain\user" 
          password="password" />
```

Comment: @user1038885 Can you login as that user from your Windows logon screen, using the same credentials?

Answer (score -1):

why do you use impersonation if everyone account is active ?

remove the impersonation Section